# using a name macro for variables from a functions inputs

Tags: macros, julia

If I have 2 variables, `a=[.3, .2, .4]; b=[.1, .2, .3];` I can create a string with the name of the variable using a macro:

```
macro varname(arg)
    string(arg)
end

@varname(a)
```

now say I have a function and I want to pass it an arbitrary number of arguments and use the actual variable names that are being given to function to create dictionary keys:

```
function test(arguments...)
    Dict(Symbol(@varname(i)) => i for i in arguments)
end
```

this won't work because `@varname` will take `i` and create `"i"`, so for example:

```
out=test(a,b)
```

the output I would like is:

```
Dict("a" => [.3, .2, .4], "b" => [.1, .2, .3])
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: If `arguments` is a variable length tuple of positional parameters then they don't have names. If on the other hand, the definition is `function test(;arguments...)` which makes `arguments` named parameters, then `Dict(a[1]=>a[2] for a in arguments)` should usually work (except for edge cases with argument names repeating etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters.jl has such a macro. It works like this:

```
using Parameters
d = Dict{Symbol,Any}(:a=>5.0,:b=>2,:c=>"Hi!")
@unpack a, c = d
a == 5.0 #true
c == "Hi!" #true

d = Dict{Symbol,Any}()
@pack d = a, c
d # Dict{Symbol,Any}(:a=>5.0,:c=>"Hi!")
```

If you want to know how it's done, just check its source:

https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl/blob/v0.7.3/src/Parameters.jl#L594